# What program is used to create this?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, map-book

What program was used to create this type of [mapbook](http://www.chapeloaksfire.com/filelocker/download/file_id/11341)?

So if I want to get my roads to look similar to the above PDF - how would I go about doing that. [image]

Comment: Doesn't look like any ArcGIS-produced map book I've seen... I know there are fire-specific mapping software packages out there that do that kind of work... not sure what they're called. Might want to get in touch with the creator or at least their office to check...?

Comment: I would agree with @mapBaker, but saying that, it is very possible to create this map book with ArcGIS given the data and graphics are created.

Comment: Definitely not ArcGIS DSmapBook or Data Driven Pages. There may be custom software that will make it, either in ArcGis, other mapping software extension or as a standalone application. It would not be impossible to make in ArcGis but would be a lot of work, in particular the map/page number moves on each page. The actual map doesn't look difficult to replicate though.

Comment: Looks like screen captures of a single large map.  Labels are cut off in corners and not optimized for the different scales.

Comment: Good Point@jakub

Comment: Turns out it is AutoCAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to be certain how it was created is by contacting the author/organisation that published it.

However, I suspect that it was created using **ArcGIS for Desktop**'s **Data Driven Pages** and **ArcPy**; and the **[ReportLab open-source PDF Toolkit](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/)** using techniques similar to those described in:

- an Esri blog entitled **[Creating Place Name Indexes for Map Books](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/11/19/creating-place-name-indexes-for-map-books/)**; and
- the Help page entitled **[Creating a map book with facing pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002p000000)**.

It is also possible that it is using the **[Fire Run Book](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b38c6c3fff844eda9b33ff54b24a349b)** tool but I have not downloaded that, and I suspect that it will use the above techniques anyway.

Comment: I don't think arcpy, let alone Data Driven Pages existed in 2009!

Comment: @blah238 ArcPy and DDP were both released 30 June 2010 so working backwards they would have been well into alpha (if not beta) during 2009 which I think would at least place them in the hands of Esri Professional Services (if they were involved).  In any event DDP did not come out of a vacuum so the map book also looks like it could have been the work of PLTS' MPS Atlas.  I suspect the asker (unless a map historian) is more likely to be interested in how to produce such a map book today.

Comment: agreed. mainly. the map itself less of the actual booklet